# jQuery - attach event to dynamic element

Tags: jquery, events, bind

I have read through the .on documentation, but there is a bug in it

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="add-new">make new row</a>

<ul>
    <li class="opts" >
        <select class="change" href="#" data-row="1">
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
            <option>c</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
 var index = 2;
 $('.add-new').on('click',function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();

     $('.opts:first').clone(true).insertAfter('.opts:last');
     $('.opts:last select').attr("data-row", index);

     index++;

 });

 $(document).on('click', '.change', function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();

     console.log($(this).data('row'));

 });
```

If I dynamically generate rows, the new elements work with the .on event.
But if the first element is changed and more new elements are added, the new new ones fire the event.
Now they act as though they are the first element.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BgAsY/2/
Add one or two rows and then change any but the first select.
The console shows the correct corresponding number when those are changed.
Now add a few more rows and change those new selects.
Everything is still fine, but now change the first select, add more rows and then change those newest selects.
The console now always shows 1, like it thinks those newest rows are the first row.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$(this).data('row')
```

to

```
$(this).attr('data-row')
```

and it seems to solve the issue.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BgAsY/6/)

Comment: I had incorrectly assumed these were the same. Thanks adeneo and Jithesh for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `console.log($(this).data('row'));` with `console.log($(this).attr('data-row'));`

**Reason for the issue:**

- When you do `$('.opts:first').clone(true)`, the new cloned object carries the data set to the original object via `data()` method
- Then you are changing the 'data-row' attribute of the cloned element instead of changing its data via `data()`, so the data('row') remains unchanged.
- And, on clicking .change you are retrieving the data using data() method which returns the data(which was not changed) rather than data-row attribute value which you changed in the last step.

**$(elm).data('row') is NOT THE SAME as $(elm).attr('data-row')**

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BgAsY/12/